# How to find points on a plane

Tags: vectors

I'm very confused by the answer to this question:

"Find the image of the plane $r\cdot(1,1,1) = 0$"

The first part of the worked answer I have been given is:

"Parameterise by $x$ and $y$, so one point on the plane is the origin $(0,0,0)$, another is $(1,0,-1)$ and another is $(0,1,-1)$."

I don't understand how the points on the plane have been found?

Comment: Let $A=(1,1,1)$, then points $B$ and $C$ must be found such that $\vec{OA}$ is orthogonal (perpendicular) to $\vec{OB}$ and $\vec{OC}$ and where $\vec{OB}$ and $\vec{OC}$ are linearly independent.  There are not unique points satisfying these conditions but the two given in your solution are two that do.

Comment: by trying it out. Just write $r=(x,y,z)$, then $r \cdot (1,1,1)= x+y+z =0$. Now find values for $x, y,z$ for which this equation is true.

Answer (score 0):

The plane can be described as "the set of all points $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $(x,y,z) \cdot (1,1,1)=0$. Three such points are $(1,0,-1)$,$(0,1,-1)$, and $(0,0,0)$. One way of finding these kinds of points if it's not too apparent is by taking the dot product, which gives the equation $x+y+z=0$ to describe the plane. Thus, for instance, all points of the form $(a,a,-2a)$ lie on the plane.